# A bug with Fight mechanic and Deathtouch in Magic DOTP 2014?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

My turn, before combat.

Opponent:

- Giant Scorpion 1/3

Me:

- Giant Scorpion 1/3

I cast Hunt the Weak selecting both Scorpions. In response to Hunt still on stack I cast Giant Growth on my Scorpion.

After Growth resolution, my Giant Scorpion was 4/6, as expected.

Now Hunt the Weak resolves and...**they both go to graveyard?!** :O

Fight mechanic **is not** dealing **combat** damage.

Deathtouch mechanic **is combat** damage and (its deadliness) should not be counted for Fight.

The outcome should have been that the oponents Scorpion should have died because of 4 dmg received and mine should have just 1 damage on his 6 toughness (and should have been able to attack for 4).

Right?
Seems like a bug in DOTP 2014 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deathtouch (and Lifelink) works with every type of damage and with Fight the creature is doing the damage. The [comprehensive rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/resources.aspx?x=magic/rules) says:

Deathtouch:

> 702.2c A creature with toughness greater than 0 that’s been dealt damage by a source with deathtouch since the last time state-based actions were checked is destroyed as a state-based action

No mention of combat damage here.

Fight:

> 701.10a A spell or ability may instruct a creature to fight another creature or it may instruct two creatures to fight each other. Each of those creatures deals damage equal to its power to the other creature.

Comment: seems valid, thanks. Then DOTP 2013 has the same (but reversed) bug because there a creature fought my creature that had deathtouch and didn't die.